# [Angular2+]How to enable horizontal scroll programatically in pdf.js with Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf.js

I need a pdf viewer with horizontal scroll, and after lot of research I found this that [ng2-pdfjs-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdfjs-viewer)could serve my purpose:

It is a wrapper for pdf.js and viewer.js.

I thought it would have the horizontal scroll option in toolbar like originally shown [here](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=), but it only provides some options of the original.

I figured I'd render individual pages and do horizontal scrolling in css, but I'm not sure if that's even possible without some hack (which I would prefer to avoid).

But the docs don't show all the methods despite them existing on the reference object, so if anyone knows a way to achieve horizontal scroll in angular2+ app: can you please shed some light as to how that can be achieved?

Either by using pdf.js, ng2-pdf,viewer or ng2-dfjs-viewer, or some other package/means?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 1):

*FYI: I am the author of this package*

To enable scroll, use the `scroll` property.

*`scroll` - Sets scroll. Available options are VERTICAL/V, HORIZONTAL/H,WRAPPED/W. Case is irrelevant.*

Usage
`<ng2-pdfjs-viewer scroll="H" pdfSrc="some.pdf" cursor="HAND" spred="E"></ng2-pdfjs-viewer>`